# mysql user from other host failing unsure why

Tags: mysql

i've setup a new mysql user on a server that allows access from other servers. i can access it from my dev machine using the credentials i setup.

But on one of my other servers nothing happens when trying to log into mysql using the same credentials that worked on my dev box. any ideas what it might be?

all it does is hang. 
Nothing gets added to log files on either the new DB server or the one i'm trying to access from.

i also tested this connection from another server, just to test if my dev box was a fluke andi could access. So all i can think is there's something "wrong" with the server i cant access from.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your query that executes to create this user and privileges.
If you can’t remember the queries you can execute this in your target server to get details about user

`SHOW GRANTS for 'root'@'localhost';`

You may check these things also .

1. Firewall setup for the server from the trouble machine.
2. Can this machine connect to another sql server provided with similar access?
3. Execute `select * from mysql.user ;` and check you don’t have duplicates with 
   different access privileges or passwords .

Answer (score 0):

turns out i had everything setup correctly, as i said i was able to use the same user across other servers just not this one.

turns out my server provider had a network firewall restricting mysql connections. removed and hey presto.

thanks @csf